# Controller crashes all games

Tags: 64-bit, crash, 32-bit, controller, 32-vs-64-bit

I have bought Esperanza EG102 (really cheap just over 4 $) controller. It has a force feedback feature, so it crashes everything, that tries to connect to it. When I run joy.cpl for a vibration test, System32 (32-bit one) crashes, however SYSWOW64 (64-bit one) doesn't crash, and force feedback test works fine, even the vibration is working. It crashes both 32-bit and 64-bit games.

If you have any questions ask me, I will reply as fast as I could.

Thanks for any help, John.